# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type! while trying to use @Query in JpaRepository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to update a string value in mysql table . For this I wrote a method as below.

```
@Repository
public interface NotificationRepository extends JpaRepository<Notification, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update Notification msg set msg.message = ?1 where msg.applicationUser.id = ?2")
    String createNewNotification(String message, Long id);

}
```

I get following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type!
```

Can't I update a string value in my table. Only void or int is possible?. Is this mean that? How do I can I handle this exception? Please help.

Comment: what part of the error message is unclear to you? *"as return type"* is the key here.

Comment: That is why i'm asking a question. If I'm clear with issue I won't

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for your answer. That have given me a quick idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error says `Modifying queries can only use void or int/Integer as return type` you can only return void or an integer/int that signify how many rows has been updated by the query.

Change that and should work without problems.

```
  @Modifying
    @Query("update Notification msg set msg.message = ?1 where msg.applicationUser.id = ?2")
    void createNewNotification(String message, Long id);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can update String values in your Database (you are already doing this by the message parameter value). You cannot return a String object as the return value of your database query as you use the @Modifying annotation. I suggest you change the return type to void or int to indicate success of failure:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Notification msg set msg.message = ?1 where msg.applicationUser.id = ?2")
void createNewNotification(String message, Long id);
```

or

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Notification msg set msg.message = ?1 where msg.applicationUser.id = ?2")
int createNewNotification(String message, Long id);
```

The int/Integer return value is the number of rows that where updated in the database. So if this is > 0 you have feedback that your query executed successfully.

Try also to give a look at the options of @Modifying.

Comment: After changing in to this I get following error javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Comment: @Sandu_prass you have to make this modifying query transactional. You can do this by using the Transactional annotation.